# how to change the nodeid in opc ua for c++ sdk

Tags: opc, opc-ua, node-opcua

**I've searched for hours on how to change the nodeID of my objects/variables in c++ OPC UA, but unfortunately can't figure it out.**

now, for example, the nodeID if ns=0;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Int32

I need to change to ns=0;i=2558

Can someone with more experience help me out here, please?

[iam using this SDK](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkcpp/1.5.5/html/L3GettingStartedClientLesson03.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Unified Automation C++ SDK, you should consider contacting them to get support for their product...

Comment: You should be aware that under no circumstances you should have a node with "ns=0;s=Demo.Dynamic.Scalar.Int32" in your server, because namespace 0 is reserved (and OPC Foundation has not defined such node). Same for "ns=0;i=2558".